# System crash log in Android 4.3 ( cm 10.2 )

Tags: cyanogenmod, crashes, htc-sensation

My rooted HTC Sensation with android 4.3 has started crashing recently. Is there any crash log where I could find out where is the problem? I'm using not-so-recent nightly version of cyanogen mod 10.2. Anyone knows?

Comment: At which point does it crash? If you can get it to completely boot, enable USB Debugging in Developer Settings, and try to run `adb logcat` in terminal (or adb shell on your PC.)

Comment: OP: Do you know how to enable Developer Settings? Go into Settings > About Phone, tap on the Build Number seven times, then proceed with @chahk 's comment above.

Comment: It boots fine, sometimes it even works for like day or two and then it crashes. I couldn't find any trigger event (which makes me think it is something with system, not with particular app).